# Get Element by Id change style element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get style in my div by using javascript, but i have one issue i don't know why. I set background-color for my div and when I click button it change my background color div but the first time when the page loaded, I have to click this button two time then my color div change. After that I have to click one time.
This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {

       var color = document.querySelector('body');
       var button = document.querySelector('button');

       console.log('OK');
       button.addEventListener('click', changeMode);
       function changeMode(evt){
              if (color.style.background=="")            //comment
                     color.style.background = 'white'; 
              if (color.style.background == 'white'){
                     color.style.background ='black';
                     color.style.color = 'white';
                     button.innerHTML='Dark';
              }
              else{
                     color.style.background ='white';
                     color.style.color = '#021373';
                     button.innerHTML='Light';
              }
       }
}
```

```html
<body>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
```

I realize if I comment line

```
   if (color.style.background=="")           
      color.style.background = 'white';
```

When page load, color.style.background is null, so I must set it "none" the first time. Someone explain for me about this problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you also include the relevant html?

Comment: Could you add your snippet to your question please?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

> but the first time when the page loaded, I have to click this button
>   two time then my color div change

That is because the default computed style of the body is white and you only check for the inset style. Check out [computes styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

### Solution

You could only set and check the `element.style.backgroundColor` property or else if you want to use `element.style.background` change your logic to check if it is empty or not.

For toggling you actually only need two steps [empty(=white) or not empty(=black)].

```js
window.onload = function() {
       var color = document.querySelector('body');
       var button = document.querySelector('button');

       button.addEventListener('click', changeMode);
       
       function changeMode(evt){
              var tColor = color.style.backgroundColor;
              if(!tColor){
                  color.style.backgroundColor ='black';
                  color.style.color = 'white';
                  button.innerHTML='Dark';
              }
              else{
                  color.style.backgroundColor ='';
                  color.style.color = '#021373';
                  button.innerHTML='Light';
              }
       }
}
```

```html
<button>Light</button>
```

**Yet, as a side note, the proper way would be to toggle a class in this case containing the style overwrites.**

```js
window.onload = function() {      
       function changeMode(evt){
              var tBody = document.querySelector('body');
              
              //REM: Check if dark
              if(tBody.classList.contains("dark")){
                tBody.classList.remove("dark");
                this.innerHTML = 'Dark'
              }
              else{
                tBody.classList.add("dark");
                this.innerHTML = 'Light'
              }
       };
       
       document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', changeMode);
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
  color: #021373
}

body.dark{
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<button>Dark</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the active color in a variable and change the value of it if it's clicked to decide what color is active. Check out my snippet:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
 
var change = "";
function myFunction() {
    if(change == "" || change == "blue"){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      change = "red";
    }else if (change == "red"){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      change = "black";
    }else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      change = "blue";
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<button type="button">Set background color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to set the background to white in the beginning.
But otherwise your check is just fine!

```js
window.onload = function() {

       var color = document.querySelector('body');
       var button = document.querySelector('button');

       console.log('OK');
       button.addEventListener('click', changeMode);
       function changeMode(evt){
              if (color.style.background == 'white'){
                     color.style.background ='black';
                     color.style.color = 'white';
                     button.innerHTML='Dark';
              }
              else{
                     color.style.background ='white';
                     color.style.color = '#021373';
                     button.innerHTML='Light';
              }
       }
}
```

```html
<body style="background: white;">
<button>Click</button>
</body>
```